Pycharm interpreter - wrong encoding
Context: Automation framework with BDD in Python 
Action: Attempt to run the code and generate behave-html report
Command used: behave -f html -o behave-report.html (html option was mapped into a behave.ini file so it is correct)
Problem: The file cannot open properly and returns error: the file was loaded in a wrong encoding utf-8
Observations:

Pycharm interpreter seems to have the wrong encoding:

Python packages seems to not be installed, but whenever I install it I get the following error:

Vvdgifdgo (qswy vigiry gdpp pdwy):
  Gmpi "<jvs�ir v{rt>", pmri 198, mr bv{rbqsh{pibdwbqdmr
  Gmpi "<jvs�ir v{rt>", pmri 88, mr bv{rbgshi
  Gmpi "D:_Qvskvdq Gmpiw_KiyCvdmrw_QDldvq Dsqq{rmy Fhmymsr 2024.2.1_tp{kmrw_tylsr-gi_liptivw_tmt-20.3.4-t2.t3-rsri-dr.}lp_tmt_bbqdmrbb.t", pmri 23, mr <qsh{pi>
  Gmpi "D:_Qvskvdq Gmpiw_KiyCvdmrw_QDldvq Dsqq{rmy Fhmymsr 2024.2.1_tp{kmrw_tylsr-gi_liptivw_tmt-20.3.4-t2.t3-rsri-dr.}lp_tmt_bmryivrdp_gpm_qdmr.t", pmri 10, mr <qsh{pi>
  Gmpi "D:_Qvskvdq Gmpiw_KiyCvdmrw_QDldvq Dsqq{rmy Fhmymsr 2024.2.1_tp{kmrw_tylsr-gi_liptivw_tmt-20.3.4-t2.t3-rsri-dr.}lp_tmt_bmryivrdp_gpm_d{ysgsqtpiymsr.t", pmri 9, mr <qsh{pi>
  Gmpi "D:_Qvskvdq Gmpiw_KiyCvdmrw_QDldvq Dsqq{rmy Fhmymsr 2024.2.1_tp{kmrw_tylsr-gi_liptivw_tmt-20.3.4-t2.t3-rsri-dr.}lp_tmt_bmryivrdp_gpm_qdmrbtdvwiv.t", pmri 7, mr <qsh{pi>
  Gmpi "D:_Qvskvdq Gmpiw_KiyCvdmrw_QDldvq Dsqq{rmy Fhmymsr 2024.2.1_tp{kmrw_tylsr-gi_liptivw_tmt-20.3.4-t2.t3-rsri-dr.}lp_tmt_bmryivrdp_gpm_gqhstymsrw.t", pmri 18, mr <qsh{pi>
Nsh{piOsyGs{rhFvvsv: Os qsh{pi rdqih 'hmwy{ympw'

Debugging attempts:

tried to modify the file encoding to utf-8 (Editor -> File Encodings)
tried to modify the console encoding (Editor -> General -> Console -> Default Encoding)
uninstalled and reinstalled python and pycharm
made sure that the path variables are up to date
recreated the interpretor and reinstalled all packages

None of them worked.
Python version: 3.12.6
Pycharm version: 2024.2.1

Perhaps from File | Settings you can try changing the values under Editor | File encodings. Not quite sure though if this can help you with non-ASCII filenames. Can you import those name from eg. the Python prompt?

@YannisP. tried it already. Not working

This can be many things perhaps even file encodings in your os. If open let’s say a Python prompt, can you import those names as you expected in non ASCII characters?

You can also ask here: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/s/zXWmcdyvNY
